# Как ввести переменную внутри цикла for в powershell? Области видимости в Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, for

Решил написать скрипт для сравнения двух папок на разных носителях (один на диске `H:\`, другой на диске `D:\`) под Windows. В случае резервного копирования может быть полезным. Написал следующий код:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /B /S /AD') do (
    set ssd=d
    echo %ssd%
    set ssd=%ssd:H:\=D:\%
    comp "%%ssd" "%%d"
    cd %%d
    echo "inside %%d"
)
```

Ожидается, что в цикле for будут рекурсивно пробегаться все вложенные папки и будет производиться сравнение папок командой comp.
Столкнулся с проблемой: команда `set ssd=d` не объявляет новую переменную. Это становится очевидно благодаря команде `echo %ssd%` - она просто печатает в консоли `echo`. Т.е. переменная ssd не создаётся вовсе! Думаю, что в цикле for своя область видимости и в Windows нужно как-то хитро объявлять подобные переменные. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильно делается?

Comment: определитесь с тем, что собираетесь использовать и оставьте только один тег языка

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать чуть более конкретно, пожалуйста?)

Comment: вы указали 5 меток, 3 из которых обозначают, на каком языке будет написан код в вопросе/ответах. никто не будет давать вам ответ на bash'е, batch'е и powershell'е одновременно

Comment: `нужно как-то хитро объявлять подобные переменные`. Да, это так. Для использования переменных в цикле нужна команда `setlocal`. Например, `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, после вызова команды (перед запуском цикла) к значению локальным переменным следует обращаться не через символ `%`, а - `!`. В Вашем случае: `!ssd!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно перепутал кучу интерпретаторов, поэтому решил проще решить задачу и написал скрипт на Python + CMD.

```
import os


def run_command(command):
    res = os.popen(command)
    for line in res:
        print(line.encode('cp1251').decode("cp866"))


command = "dir /B /S /AD"
dirs_inside = list(os.popen(command))
for dir_ in enumerate(dirs_inside):
    dirs_inside[dir_[0]] = dir_[1][:-1]
cur_dir = os.getcwd()
all_dirs = [cur_dir] + dirs_inside

disk = 'H'
command_template = 'comp "{path_1}" "{path_2}"'
for dir_ in all_dirs:
    path1 = disk + dir_[1:]
    path2 = dir_
    cur_command = command_template.format(path_1=path1, path_2=path2)
    run_command(cur_command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не пошутили насчёт PowerShell, приведя скрипт для `cmd`, то для рекурсивного сравнения файлов не требуются переменные.

```
gci -Recurse .\PAPKA\ | `
  where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | `
  % { $_.FullName } | `
  % { fc.exe "$_" "$($_.Replace('D:','H:'))" }
```

Этот скриптик

- рекурсивно пройдёт по всем файлам из папки с именем PAPKA (каталоги будут отфильтрованы инструкцией `where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }`),
- для каждого файла добудет строку, содержащую полный путь к файлу
- вызовет утилиту [`fc.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc), заменив во втором параметре строку `D:` на строку `H:`

Если вам нужно именно `comp`, то замените `fc.exe` на `comp.exe`, хотя я бы не советовал.

Второе. В PowerShell нужно вызывать именно `fc.exe`, так как простое `fc` - это алиас на команду `Format-Custom`.

Answer (score 0):

В пакетных файлах области видимости всех переменных глобальные, проблема не в них. Проблема в том, что %%-переменные раскрываются в момент начала выполнения команды, а она у вас одна - весь цикл for.

Для решения этой проблемы следует использовать ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION и !!-переменные:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /B /S /AD') do (
    set ssd=d
    echo !ssd!
    set ssd=!ssd:H:\=D:\!
    comp "!ssd!" "%%d"
    cd %%d
    echo "inside %%d"
)
```